# Display text in time intervals with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to create, using the `setInterval()` JS function, a visual effect that displays text one character at the time with an interval of `100`ms per character, on an Angular application.

Note that this happens in the `index.html` within the `<app-root>` tags, so it will appear only while the app is bootstrapped.
After reading the `setInterval()` [page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) i thought that this would make the job, so this is my code:

```js
var divs=['rBox','aBox','tBox','sBox'];
var index=-1;

function displayChars(){
  for(container of divs){
    document.getElementById(container).style.visibility='hidden';  
  }
  var fun = setInterval(display,100);
}

function display(){
  if(index < 4){
    document.getElementById(divs[++index]).style.visibility='visible'
  }else{
    clearInterval(fun);
  }
}
displayChars();
```

```html
<app-root>
  <div class="rats-div">
    <div id="rBox">1</div>
    <div id="aBox">2</div>
    <div id="tBox">3</div>
    <div id="sBox">4..</div>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

But it does not display anything, the divs containing the numbers are there with visibility set to `hidden` but it seems like they are never set to `visible`

I can't see where the problem lies. If I look at the code from an algorithmic point of view, I guess I probably don't understand very well the inner working of `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fun` was not declared globally

And `index` was incremented too much

A rough update to the code:

```js
var divs=['rBox','aBox','tBox','sBox'];
var index=-1;
var fun
function displayChars(){
  for(container of divs){
    document.getElementById(container).style.visibility='hidden';  
  }
  fun = setInterval(display,100);
}

function display(){
  if(index < 3){
    document.getElementById(divs[++index]).style.visibility='visible'
  }else{
    clearInterval(fun);
  }
}
displayChars()
```

```html
<app-root>
  <div class="rats-div">
    <div id="rBox">1</div>
    <div id="aBox">2</div>
    <div id="tBox">3</div>
    <div id="sBox">4..</div>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

Answer (score 2):

After minor modifications it's working, see below. I changed index to start at 0 and to be used with `divs[index++]` (so use-then-increment), and to compare it with `divs.length` instead of hardcoded `4`. Also I put variable `fun` at the global level.

```js
var divs = ['rBox', 'aBox', 'tBox', 'sBox'];
var index = 0;
var fun = -1; // timer handle

function displayChars() {
  for (container of divs) {
    document.getElementById(container).style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  fun = setInterval(display, 100);
}

function display() {
  if (index < divs.length) {
    document.getElementById(divs[index++]).style.visibility = 'visible'
  } else {
    clearInterval(fun);
  }
}

displayChars();
```

```html
<div class="rats-div">
  <div id="rBox">1</div>
  <div id="aBox">2</div>
  <div id="tBox">3</div>
  <div id="sBox">4..</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your variable `fun` needs to be global, otherwise `display()` can't
  access it
- Don't forget to declare `container` in your `for...of` loop as an actual variable
- You where incrementing `index` too often

```js
var divs = ['rBox', 'aBox', 'tBox', 'sBox'];
var index = -1;
var fun;

function displayChars() {
  for (var container of divs) {
    document.getElementById(container).style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  fun = setInterval(display, 100);
}

function display() {
  if (index < 3) {
    document.getElementById(divs[++index]).style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    clearInterval(fun);
  }
}
displayChars();
```

```html
<app-root>
  <div class="rats-div">
    <div id="rBox">1</div>
    <div id="aBox">2</div>
    <div id="tBox">3</div>
    <div id="sBox">4..</div>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure *CSS* solution, if an option, looks something like this:

```css
.rats-div > div {
  opacity: 0; /* or "visibility: hidden" */
  animation: opacity .1s forwards;
}

.rats-div > div:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: .1s}
.rats-div > div:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: .2s}
.rats-div > div:nth-child(4) {animation-delay: .3s}

@keyframes opacity {
  to {opacity: 1} /* or "visibility: visible / initial" */
}
```

```html
<div class="rats-div">
  <div id="rBox">1</div>
  <div id="aBox">2</div>
  <div id="tBox">3</div>
  <div id="sBox">4..</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var divs=['rBox','aBox','tBox','sBox'];
var index=0;
var fun=null;
function displayChars(){
  for(container of divs){
    document.getElementById(container).style.visibility='hidden';
  }
  fun = setInterval(display,100);
}

function display(){
  if(index < 4){
    document.getElementById(divs[index]).style.visibility='visible'
    index++;
  }else{
    clearInterval(fun);
  }
}

displayChars();
```

```html
<app-root>
        <div class="rats-div">
          <div id="rBox">1</div>
          <div id="aBox">2</div>
          <div id="tBox">3</div>
          <div id="sBox">4..</div>
        </div>
    </app-root>
```

try this code. it should do your job.